# The label file of PointNet

Tags: python, deep-learning

Recently, I studied the project, which is about point cloud classification by deep learning.
https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet

I wanted to test the project by my own data.
The file it read is HDF5.
It provided some tools to generate those files.
https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet/blob/master/utils/data_prep_util.py

For example, in

```
data_prep_util.py line 79
def save_h5(h5_filename, data, label, data_dtype='uint8', label_dtype='uint8'):
```

The second parameter, 'data', is a numpy array of ply file, and can generate by the function in line 119?

My question is the third parameter, 'label'.
I don't know the file format of 'label'.
I searched the entire project and didn't see possible sample files.

What is the file format of 'label'?
Can everyone provide some examples?

Comment: please provide your research and particular code block and error specific to the data being talked about here in the question

Answer (score 0):

.lable file is only a simple text file. .lable file have the information about the what label you have given to the certain collection of point cloud. THIS .LABLE file is generated using segmentation and annotation tool